# How can I eliminate comma at end of lines in CSV for Pandas Dataframe when only some have them?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, csv

I am trying to convert a csv file to pandas df.
The data is of the following type (SROIE dataset) (this is just a small part of total file):

```
76,50,323,50,323,84,76,84,TAN WOON YANN
110,165,315,165,315,188,110,188,INDAH GIFT & HOME DECO
126,191,297,191,297,214,126,214,27,JALAN DEDAP 13,
129,218,287,218,287,236,129,236,TAMAN JOHOR JAYA,
100,243,324,243,324,261,100,261,81100 JOHOR BAHRU,JOHOR.
70,268,201,268,201,285,70,285,TEL:07-3507405
```

**THE ISSUE LIES ONLY IN THE LAST COLUMN, WHICH DOESN'T DISPLAY THE ENTIRE TEXT INFORMATION I NEED.**
Based on an answer I found on [pandas dataframe read csv with rows that have/not have comma at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47519294/11696151) , I used the following code:

```
pd.read_csv(r'D:\E_Drive\everything else\C2\SROIE2019\0325updated.task1train(626p)\X00016469619.txt',usecols=np.arange(0,9), header=None)
```

This gave the following output:
[image: Pandas Dataframe Result I got]

The problem is that, for example in line 3 (row labelled 2 in pd dataframe)i.e.

```
126,191,297,191,297,214,126,214,27,JALAN DEDAP 13,
```

I need

> 27,JALAN DEDAP 13,

but I am getting

> 27

only. Same is the issue in line 5 (row labelled 4 in pd dataframe):

```
100,243,324,243,324,261,100,261,81100 JOHOR BAHRU,JOHOR.
```

I need

> 81100 JOHOR BAHRU,JOHOR.

but I am getting

> 81100 JOHOR BAHRU

Comment: The problem isn't the comma at the end, but the comma in the middle of string.  Comma is used the column delimiter, separating the other fields.  But in the last column some entries have their own internal comma, which the reader interprets as a column delimiter.

Comment: If the structure is always 7 columns and then possibly a string containing commas, you can simply read all the columns in the csv, keep the first 7 and then concatenate the remaining ones. Not a general solution but should work as long as the structure stays the same as you outlined here. I think the right solution here would be, if possible, to export the csv using a different separator than a comma, e.g. a pipe (|)

Comment: How do I do that? If I  choose a different number of columns per row to start with before even concatenation process, an error is thrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach might be sufficient?  It first reads the rows using a standard CSV reader and rejoins the end columns before loading it into pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

with open('X00016469619.txt', newline='') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    data = [row[:8] + [', '.join(row[8:])] for row in csv_input]
        
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Giving you:

```
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7                          8
0   76   50  323   50  323   84   76   84              TAN WOON YANN
1  110  165  315  165  315  188  110  188     INDAH GIFT & HOME DECO
2  126  191  297  191  297  214  126  214       27, JALAN DEDAP 13, 
3  129  218  287  218  287  236  129  236         TAMAN JOHOR JAYA, 
4  100  243  324  243  324  261  100  261  81100 JOHOR BAHRU, JOHOR.
5   70  268  201  268  201  285   70  285             TEL:07-3507405
```